# Тире или двоеточие

Tags: пунктуация

В каком случае не будет ошибкой в предложении поставить либо тире, либо двоеточие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все разъехались: стало нестерпимо скучно. (=потому что стало скучно)
Все разъехались - стало нестерпимо скучно. (=стало скучно, когда все разъехались)
В данных предложениях и интонация разная: в первом на стыке частей интонация вниз, во втором - вверх.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще-то это противоположные знаки.Значит должно быть такое предложение, где за одними и и теми же словами скрывается противоположный смысл.

Answer (score 2):

У тире два значения: разделительное и присоединительное, они передают разную интонацию. По смыслу в приведенном примере подходит присоединительное тире, именно оно обычно заменяет двоеточие. Присоединительное тире обозначает добавочный характер сообщения - в данном случае добавочный характер пояснения, когда по классическим правилам должно ставится двоеточие. Интонация  присоединительного тире и двоеточия похожа - это понижение голоса перед паузой, но в случае двоеточия пауза более длительная, предупреждающая нас о последующем пояснении, раскрытии темы.